# using sed parameters \1, \2 in the same expression side

Tags: sed

I have a text file with many equations of the following format:

```
somePtrName->ARRAY[0] == somePtrName->ARRAY[0]
```

Whenever **the pointer names are the same**, I want to use `sed` to replace the line and write `true` instead. I tried the following recipe,
but it didn't work:

```
$ sed 's/[^=]* == \1/true/' input.txt
```

I got:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: Invalid back reference
```

Maybe I was too naive to believe I can use `\1` in the same side it was defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the chars first  by adding brackets around the pattern which are intended for catching, then only you could backreference it.

```
sed 's/\([^=]*\) == \1/true/' input.txt
```

or

```
sed 's/\([^=]\+\) == \1/true/' <<<"somePtrName->ARRAY[0] == somePtrName->ARRAY[0]"
true
```

always try to capture one or more chars otherwise, it would return true for empty rows like `==` if you used `*`

Also better to anchor your regex `^`, `$`  inorder to avoid part of the text to get matched.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, this should be easy in `awk` if you ok with it.

```
awk -F'->| ' '$1==$4{print "true"}'  Input_file
```

Comment: It may be since it was asked for `sed`.  But user who down vote should write why.  Gave you +1 so you are on 0 again :)

Comment: @Jotne, Thank you buddy :)